# Detecting angle and curly brackets in RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, textbox

I have a regular expression to validate a text box to only allow particular characters. The expression currently I have is

```
pattern = "^([-_,A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&()=+;'.~`]{1,60})$";
```

to report an error if a character other than is input. This works perfectly. Now I want to allow `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` (the square and curly brackets) as valid characters. I tried including these but the `IsMatch` method always returns false if I include them in the pattern I have. I added them as follows,

```
pattern = "^([-_,A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&()[]{}=+;'.~`]{1,60})$";
```

I tested this for only alpha numeric string value. `IsMatch` returns false on that too. I pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the new thing included.

Can any one let me know what's wrong in the modified pattern?

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the square brackets inside the square brackets.

```
pattern = "^([-_,A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&()\[\]{}=+;'.~`]{1,60})$";
```

BTW: {} are braces, or curly braces, not angle brackets.

Comment: Are the other characters (like period, for example) treated as a literal when inside the square brackets?

Comment: @Tim: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#PositiveGroup

Comment: Inside square brackets, only -, ^, \, and ] are special, and the first two only by position.  Only \ and ] have to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - thanks for the link.  I'll keep it bookmarked.  I used to do a lot of RegEx, now only occassionally.

Comment: [POSIX also has special treatment for colon (`:`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) but doesn't use escaping at all.  be interesting to see whether those guidelines for special characters (`]` at the beginning, `-` at the end) work correctly in .NET.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your regex to be portable, put the closing square bracket first and hyphen last, as discussed here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

```
pattern = "^([][_,A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&(){}=+;'.~`-]{1,60})$";
```

Comment: Thanks you all for the replies. I appreciate the links to educate me more and not to just giving a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all regex flavors follow those conventions.  In Java, for example, you always have to escape square brackets--opening **and** closing--no matter where you place them.  And of course, you have to escape the escapes to get past the string-literal processing.  `"[][-]"` in C# becomes `"[\\]\\[-]"` in Java.

Comment: @Alan: I'm not really concerned with Java's problems.  If Java doesn't follow the conventions supported by POSIX, Perl, awk, sed, vim, and even newcomers like .NET, that's a bug in Java, not in the convention.

Comment: You must be using a different definition of "portable" than I am.  Java doesn't claim to be POSIX compliant, so this hardly counts as a bug, annoying as it is.  Come to think of it, neither does .NET; it may follow the positional-escaping convention, but it doesn't support POSIX "character classes" like `[:alpha:]`.

Comment: @Alan: If something works in 5/7 implementations, that's "portable".  For 7/7 I'd use "universal".